# How to do an international call?

Tags: android, android-intent, internationalization, call

I am using this:

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + phone));
startActivity(callIntent);
finish();
```

to do phone calls and it works great, but now I have to do some international calls from the app, where I should use the plus' sign (+) to identify the country (ex: +01198765432)

**How may I do this without get any error?**

Comment: Please, show an error. I made it last year, there were no errors.

Answer (score 1):

You need to ad "+" sign in phone number:
Like this:

```
String phone="+123456789"
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:"+phone));
startActivity(callIntent);
```